# Unreal Engine 4 wheels at base bone

Tags: collision-detection, unreal-engine4

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxmpqShj-dM) to make a vehicle in Unreal Engine 4.

However, when I began the simulation, I found that the wheels went through the floor, and the base hit the ground.  Looking at the collision using the console, I found that all the wheel colliders were in the center!

I have rebuilt and retried to make the vehicle many times, but the wheels remain unmoving in the center.  What is going wrong?

[image: Blender]

[image: Blueprint]

[image: Gameplay]

Comment: I have exactly the samne problem... Thats annoying

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will be useful to someone.

In Blender you should set `Unit System` to `Metric` and `Unit Scale` to `0.01`.
After that, if you already have model opened or created in another scale, most probably you should upscale it 100 times. (A → S → 100).

[image]

Before import you need to apply transforms (A(to select all) → Ctrl + A → All transforms).